# Servidor online e Unity 3d

Tags: lado-do-servidor, cliente-servidor, unity3d, jogos, redes

Considerando um jogo criado no [unity-3d](/questions/tagged/unity-3d) . O que deveríamos saber para torná-lo um massive multi player online?

Comment: Essa pergunta está muito ampla, e provavelmente será fechada como tal. Procure torná-la mais específica, contextualizando mais (que tipo de jogo está fazendo, quais são seus requisitos), dizendo o que você já sabe e o que falta saber, etc. Pois uma resposta completa sobre desenvolvimento de MMOGs provavelmente daria um livro inteiro...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua pergunta foi bastante sem nexo, mais o que eu entendi relacionado a sua pergunta:

**O Que deveria levar em conta para saber criar um jogo Multiplayer Online.**

Para desenvolver um Game Multiplayer, sendo ele 3º Pessoa ou não, deveria entender como funciona o **[Ping](http://www.tecmundo.com.br/internet/715-o-que-e-ping-.htm)** e o **[FPS](http://fpsactiongames.blogspot.com.br/p/o-que-e-fps.html)**.

Você necessariamente teria que entender bastante sobre ambos se por acaso o game venha a ter uma necessidade de ser baixado, que é bem mais complexo. No caso de ter que baixa-lo teria que ter experiência em **Cloud Computing**(Computação em Nuvem) e/ou **Servidores Data centers**.

Em relação ao **Unity-3d** conhecido como Unity 3D, é um motor de jogo 3D proprietário e uma IDE criado pela Unity Technologies. Unity é similar ao Blender, Virtools ou Torque Game Engine, em relação a sua forma primária de autoria de jogos.
O Unity possui duas versões principais: Unity Pro, que custa US$ 1.500,00, e a versão gratuita, simplesmente chamada Unity, que pode ser usada tanto para fins educacionais, quanto para fins comerciais, além disso, é possível adquirir as versões gratuita e a Unity Pro por download no site oficial da unity tecnologies, sendo que a versão de download da Unity pro pode ser testada por um período de 30 dias.

E a própria empresa em seu site da uma ideia basicamente dos componentes e o necessário para a sua criação e o que é e poderá ser feito em sua plataforma.

**ABS:** [Site da Unity](http://unity3d.com/), na minha opinião ela não seria a Ideal para dar inicio a um Game bem avançado, mais a plataforma é ótima para gerar uma renda se empenhar ou até mesmo ter criatividade de criar um jogo bom, tanto que jogos feito na plataforma da **unity** quando são bem elaborados ela sempre da lances para compra-los mais fica a seu critério.

Comment: Apesar da pergunta já estar suspensa, resolvi comentar na sua resposta porque há algumas colocações que não estão lá muito corretas. :) (1) Blender não tem como função primária a autoria de jogos. (2) FPS (first person shooter) é um estilo de jogo, e não tem necessariamente a ver com o jogo ser multiplayer ou não. (3) A Unity, assim como o Torque, são motores de jogos bastante profissionais, de modo que embora a sua *opinião* seja de que eles não servem para games "avançados", eles são muito utilizados para tal e incluem suporte para comunicação em rede necssário em jogos multiplayer.